# ASP.NET MVC 3 Razor : Send JavaScript array to controller

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, data-binding

In my view I have a grid panel represents a list of warnings. When I select one item from the grid panel (one warning), I want to create a popup window to show some details of the selected warning. 
The main view:

```
@model IEnumerable<warning>
// some code
warningsGridPanel.Listeners.ItemClick.Fn = "selected";
// some code
@section JavaScript
{
   <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("/wis.js")"></script>
   <script>
         var selected = function (dv, record, item, index, e) {
           var warnings = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
            window.open("/Examples/WarningDetail?wrng=" + warnings[index], "_blank", "left=100,top=100,width=400,height=300,toolbar=1,resizable=0");
       };
    </script>  
}
```

In the controller I want to get the selected warning in order to create a new view warningDetail.

```
public ActionResult WarningDetail(warning wrng)
{
    return View(wrng);
}
```

But the object wrng is always null!
Whats the best way to send one element from JavaScript array to WarningDetail action???

Comment: Declaration of warning ?

Comment: You can make this array as comma seperated string and then get your data as (string wrng)

Comment: @Sid warning is a model

Answer (score 0):

You should send warningId or index instead of whole warning plain object, because it is already exist on the back end, the workload on network is less. In case you want to send whole object - use post request and send warning object as post data.

Comment: in this case, how can i access List<warning> in the controller ?

Comment: If warnings list exists on the backend you should get them the same way as for your initial page with grid panel. Otherwise you have several options: 1. send warning via query parameter, using JSON.stringify(warnings[index])  than on server use JSON.parse(warningString) 2. send warning via post request 3. use javascript to render warning details without calling back end's controller, with help of libraries like jquery or knockoutjs

Comment: this is not a good approch since data in not stored in controller